# How to create design which overlaps background design in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-library, android-design-library

How to create with card type layout which comes out from background design and also which overlaps on click of the button. I really don't know how to create a design of the below screenshot. Please guide me.

I am new to this design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using frame layout as base you can draw view or layout above each other. [Frame layout sample here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set theme of your `Activity` to a transparent theme. Here's an example of such a theme -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then, in your `Activity` declaration in the manifest, use the theme -

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

This gives you a transparent background of the `Activity`. You can further handle opacity of your `View`s using the `setAlpha` method of `View`. In that way you can change the opacity of the root `View` element in your layout as your requirement.